# How to make group like structure in HTML using JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have data source like this

```
var source = [
    {
        group: "g-one",
        item: "one"
    },
    {
        group: "g-one",
        item: "two"
    },
    {
        group: "g-one",
        item: "three"
    },
    {
        group: "g-two",
        item: "aaa"
    },
    {
        group: "g-two",
        item: "bbb"
    }
];
```

from this i need to create a structure like this

```
<div id='g-one'>
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
</div>
<div id='g-two'>
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>bbb</div>
</div>
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Thanks for the structuring :)

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery Way**

Get the groups out first like this :

```
var groups = $.unique($.map(source, function (n) {
    return n.group;
}));
```

Iterate over `groups` array and get the output :

```
$.each(groups, function (i, data) {
    $("<div/>", {
        "id": data.group,
        "html": function () {
              var elmts = $.grep(source, function (a) {
                return a.group === data;
              });
              return $.map(elmts, function (n) {
                  return "<div>" + n.item + "</div>";
              }).join(" ");
         }
    }).appendTo("body");
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/nZTvp/6/

**Using only JavaScript**

Use a `for` loop to iterate and create an element. To just get the string, use string concatenation.

```
    var group = source[0].group;
    var html = "<div id='" + group + "'>";
    var elemts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= source.length; i++) {
    if (i !== source.length) {
        if (group === source[i].group) {
            html += "<div>" + source[i].item + " </div>";
        } else {
            html += "</div>";
            elemts.push(html);
            group = source[i].group;
            html = "<div id='" + group + "'><div>" + source[i].item + " </div>";
        }
    } else {
        html += "</div>";
        elemts.push(html);
    }
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/nZTvp/5/

Comment: can you do it with JS alone without jQuery?

Comment: @AkbarAli check answer now. Updated it. if you want a JS only soln i would suggest u dont tag jquery in the question

Comment: Thanks for your effort passionateCoder. But the situation here is slightly different. I am inside the a JS file which can be considered as a "View" from where i send the HTML elements as string and from the main.js i append the string to the respective Element, so i would like to get output in string, Any hope?

Comment: so basically, you'd generate the output u put in the question in a string, pass it over somewhere which will take care of appending it to the element?

Comment: Yup, exactly that is the idea

Comment: so @AkbarAli okay. check this demo. http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/nZTvp/3/

This will give u a string output in an alert. Tell me if this is what u need.

Comment: no, there should be one container Div for each group, all the items (here two groups ,`g-one` and `g-two`)  inside each group, the corresponding element should have divs

Comment: Yup it did, but since it is in fiddle, i cannot accept answer here, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
var source = [ { group: "g-one", item: "one" }, { group: "g-one", item: "two" }, { group: "g-one", item: "three" }, { group: "g-two", item: "aaa" }, { group: "g-two", item: "bbb" } ]; 
    var a=new Array(); 
    for(var i=0;i<source.length;i++)
    {
        a[i]=source[i].group;   
    }
    b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        b[a[i]] = a[i];
    }
    c = [];
    for (var key in b) 
    {
        c.push(key);
    }
    var message = "";
    for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
        message+="<div id = '"+c[i]+"'>"
        for(var j=0;j<source.length;j++)
        {
            if(c[i] == source[j].group)
            {
                message+="<div>"+source[j].item+"</div>";

            }


        }
        message+="</div>";
    }
    alert(message);
```